# Restrict special characters in angular reactive forms using custom validators

Tags: angular

I want to restrict special characters in angular reactive forms using custom Validators. i have searched in stack overflow  but nothing works as expected.

```
HTML.TS
<input matInput placeholder="no symbols" formControlName="symbols" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
  <mat-error *ngIf="signupForm.controls['symbols'].hasError('symbols')">
    symbols are not allowed
  </mat-error>
```

```
CUSTOM VALIDATOR.TS
export function symbolsOnly(control: AbstractControl) {
    if ( /^[^`~!@#$%\^&*()_+={}|[\]\\:';"<>?,./]*$/.test(control.value)) {
      return { symbols: true };
    }
    return null;
    }
```

```
COMPONENT.TS
 'symbols':new FormControl("",[symbolsOnly])
```

Can someone help me on how i can restrict special characters in angular reactive forms using custom validators

Comment: No need of custom validator, you can use Validators.pattern to test string against a regex

Comment: Put the custom validator function in component file or make it static, so with class name you can use in component.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning error on valid state, try this

```
export function symbolsOnly(control: AbstractControl) {
    if ( !/^[^`~!@#$%\^&*()_+={}|[\]\\:';"<>?,./]*$/.test(control.value)) {
      return { symbols: true };
    }
    return null;
    }
```

Comment: Many thanks it worked , one more help if i want to add minimum and maximum number of characters like ` if ( !/^[^`~!@#$%\^&*()_+={}|[\]\\:';"<>?,./]*${4,20}/.test(control.value)) { `it throws me error . Do you have any idea on how to add minimum and maximum to this custom Validator . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

here is example for you
this does the special character validation

```
  symbols: ["", Validators.compose([Validators.pattern("^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9  !\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~€£¥₩])(?=.*?[A-Z 0-9]).{8,}$"), Validators.required])],
```

Answer (score 2):

In component.ts

```
//Validates that the field only contains letters or digits, you can modify the regex accordingly

const symbols = new FormControl('', Validators.pattern('[a-zA-Z0-9]*'));

console.log(symbols.errors); // {pattern: {requiredPattern: '^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$',actualValue: ''}}
```

For reference https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators#pattern

Answer (score 1):

Your way is rite but you should use `ValidatorFn` interface to return error map for reactive `formControl`.

reactive form field in component.

**field1 : new FormControl('', forbiddenStringValidator(regex))**

Create separate file for custom validation And customer validator to that like

```
export function forbiddenStringValidator(stringRe: RegExp): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): {[key: string]: any} | null => {
    const forbidden = stringRe.test(control.value);
    return forbidden ? {'forbiddenString': {value: control.value}} : null;
  };
```

[note]: REGEX should be according to the requirement.